# plot_summs - how to display reference group for ordinal/nominal variable

Tags: r, regression, visualization

I would like to visually display a row for the reference group in plot_summs with a point estimate to highlight that group for comparison (i.e., similar to coefplot's "baselevels" sub-option in Stata). I wondered if plot_summs' facet.rows sub-option could be part of the solution, but I cannot find an example of this. In the below example, I would like to have a point estimate at 1.0 for the iris species "I. setosa" (i.e., the reference group for that factor column).

In my real data, I also have reference groups that need to appear in a certain order. For example, in an 'age group' variable, "25-39 years" is the Ref, so I need it to appear in the middle of the other ordered groups, not before the other factor levels of the variable, as in the below example.

```
    # Required packages:
    library(ggplot2)
    library(jtools)
    
    # Generalized linear model with sepal length as outcome and sepal width and species as covariates:
    r <- glm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width+Species,
             data=iris,
             family=poisson(link="log"))
    
    # Visualizing measures of association:
    plot_summs(r,
               exp=TRUE,
               coefs=c("Sepal width"="Sepal.Width",
                       # Enter a row for reference group of "Species" here?
                       "I. versicolor"="Speciesversicolor",
                       "I. virginica"="Speciesvirginica"
               ),
               groups=list(" "="Sepal width",
                           "Species"=c(
                             # And add Ref here as well?
                             "I. versicolor",
                             "I. virginica"
                           )
               ),
               facet.label.pos="left"
    )+xlab("Adjusted Prevalence Ratio")
```